# Restrict login if user is disabled in Laravel not working quite well

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make simple admin function to disable/enable users rather than delete them.

So far I have admin function which successfully update table users and change the status to 0(enabled) and 1(disabled).

Now I have problems when user trying to log and checking his status.

This is my function for login in `UserController.php`

```
public function loginSubmit() {     

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

    $user = User::where('is_disabled', 0)->first();
    if ($user->is_disabled == 1) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'User not found.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }       

    $user->last_login = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
    Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

The problem is that when the condition is true `($user->is_disabled == 1)` it is logged me in with the next user from table e.g. first user which is is_disabled = 0.

How can I make this in proper way?

Comment: `User::where('is_disabled', 0)->first()` literally only selects the first user where `is_disabled` is `0`...

Comment: Use middleware instead of this black magic...

Comment: I would if I know how. I'm not that advanced and just trying to learn it from the basics.

Comment: @Ivan Oh this is laravel-4 never mind... why on earth write stuff using unsupported framework version? Do you see major developers develop games for Windows XP? Legacy? rewrite it! Have fun.

Comment: @Kyslik, I will. Once I get basics and create this application which is basically blog cms I will then rewrite it. Thanks.

Comment: That's a weird way of doing it. First write it in an old version just to rewrite it in a newer version (which can deal with this in a totally different way). Save time and write it in the correct version from the start instead.

Comment: I know. Just .. I've already spent some time on this and will finish it in 1-2 days. Anyway, thanks for the help once again.

Comment: In reality you finish this in 1-2 days + 2 weeks... This question generated way too much reputation, I don't like it.

Comment: @Kyslik, in reality are 1-2 days because is tutorial, online course which I follow. Sorry if you're not liking how people are learning things. Different people - different ways of learn.

Comment: @Ivan Laravel 5.4 is out of date "already" since core is focusing on 5.5 and you are wasting time on L4, just pick up this free course https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Comment: Okay. Thank's for the course!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem when you get user with usernaem, after that you get another user, please use firt getted user and everything should work.

```
public function loginSubmit() {     

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }

 //   $user = User::where('is_disabled', 0)->first(); //why you get one more user here you should use $user above. , remove this line
    if ($user->is_disabled == 1) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'User not found.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }       

    $user->last_login = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
    Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks. It's make sense to not create new user when I already had one.

Answer (score 1):

you have made things a bit complicated, i dont know why you are checking the user 2 times, try something like this, hope it will help

```
$user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first(['is_disabled']);
    if (!$user || $user->is_disabled==1) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
    }
else if($user && $user->is_disabled==0){
the code you want to process for logged in user
}
else{
 $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return Redirect::to('/users/login')->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For now I prefer to stick with two times check and will simply delete the second user creation as other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code `$user = User::where('is_disabled', 0)->first();` is unnecessary and fetches the wrong user.

```
public function redirectWithError($errors)
{
    return Redirect::to('/users/login')
        ->withErrors($errors)
        ->withInput(Input::except(['captcha']));
}

public function loginSubmit()
{

    $user = User::where('username', Input::get('username'))->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'Invalid login or password.');
        return $this->redirectWithError($validator->errors());
    }

    if ($user->is_disabled == 1) {
        $validator->messages()->add('username', 'User not found.');
        return $this->redirectWithError($validator->errors());
    }

    $user->last_login = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
    Session::put('user', ['user_id' => $user->user_id]);

    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```